How to understand the power of an area light
(Modified the question to make it clearer.)
I am new to Blender and working on an orthographic image projector using an area light. I used an image texture node for the emission and set the light spread to 1 degree (Please tell me if I can set the light spread to 0 degree to make it an ideal orthographic projection).

I have a question about the power of the area light. In my case, I want the image projected onto a parallel plane to match the original image in intensity. I've noticed there's a difference in intensity that seems to follow a specific ratio. I need to figure out what this ratio is.
Here's what I did:

Use Cycles renderer
Set up a diffuse BSDF plane (color value=1, roughness=0) at a distance of 1 meter from the area light. (I think this can produce a pure standard Lambertian white plane)
Turned off background (environment) lighting.
Configured the area light with the following settings:

Power: 1W
Size: 1 meter x 1 meter
Spread: 1 degree
Emission color: (1, 1, 1)
Strength: 1




After rendering, the plane's color was approximately RGB (0.312, 0.312, 0.312). I checked the intensity in the raw linear space in the .exr file.
My question is: Why is the RGB value 0.312, compared to the emission color (1, 1, 1)? To match the intensity of the area light's emission on the plane, I need to set the power to 3.2W for a 1 meter x 1 meter area light. (Interestingly, 3.2 is close to π.) I would like to know the reason why 1W energy corresponds to 0.312 pixel value.
I also tested with the plane at distances of 2 meters and 5 meters from the light, and the results were similar. It seems there's no light decay (/atmosphere) in Blender.
Can anyone explain this number of the area light's power?

The plane's resulting color is dependent on the Color Management settings as well, not just on the strength and distance of the area light... and why exactly do you think 1 W of energy should result in an RGB value of (1, 1, 1) on the plane? (Just a quick side note: the "interesting" close to π strength value of 3.2 makes the RGB values of the plane not 1, only about 0.816 if I render it with my usual AgX at Medium High Contrast setting... so much for Color Management influence.)
The Strength setting in the Emission shader is a multiplier for the Power setting in Watts which, so if you set the area light to a Power of 1 W, and the Strength to 5, this results in an area light with 5 W, just for clarification if this was not clear.
And yes, there is light decay in Blender, quadratic if you do not change it with a Light Falloff node. Light decays as it spreads. With a spread of 1° although it is barely noticeable at short distances. But here is a comparison:

At 100 m it becomes obvious that there is light decay. And with an even wider spread this is noticeable at shorter distances, too.
With 0° there is actually no spread and therefore no decay - but in reality there is never 0° spread. But this brings me to your question about the orthographic projection and if it is possible by setting the spread to 0°: honestly, ever thought of just setting it to 0° and see what happens? Here is an example with the area light at a height of 100 m above the plane at a spread of 0°:

As you can see, even at this height it still just lits a 1 m × 1 m part of the plane, so yes - it is orthographic. In the example I also have an image projected - as you can see, you can simply plug a texture into the Color input, no need to use a Geometry node in there as well (unless you need it for something specific of course).
Additional information on the Power of lights (except for the Sun light): the Watts you set there is not the electrical Watts you find printed on light bulbs. It is Radiant Flux or Radiant Power (see: Wikipedia article "Radiant flux"). Find out more about Blender's light sources and examples for power settings etc. in the Blender manual about Light Objects.

Thank you so much for the reply! I didn't make it clear. Color management is not used in my case. I am working on the raw linear space, so I check on the .ext output. Could you please check if setting 1w for a 1mX1m area light, the resulting plane is around 0.312 on your side? I didn't expect it to be 1. Whatever the number is, I need to know the reason to check if my observed number '0.312' is theoretically correct.

I agree with you that the zero degree spread seems impossible in reality. However, I am researching a new rendering model. The orthographic projection is used as interval  representation. 1 degree is a good approximation, but zero is better.

Thank you for telling me about the Geometry node. I used it just because other people showed it in their example.

When I check directly in the render result (right-click on the image to see the value of the pixel below the cursor), with View Transform > Raw and Look > None I get RGB values around 0.318 with a Roughness of 0 on the Diffuse BSDF, and 0.247 for a Roughness of 1. No idea which resembles a Lambertian white plane? In my interpretation diffusion in all directions would be correct (i.e. Roughness = 1). And as I said with the 0°: when you think it is better than 1° why didn't you just try to use it? For more info on the power settings I've added a paragraph at the end of my answer.

Thank you for checking it again! The reason I didn't use 0 degree is the minimum spread angle in the Blender ( V3.3) I used is 1 degree. I don't know how to set it to 0 degree. Which Blender version do you use?

I have Blender 4.1.1, 4.0.2 and 3.6.9... don't know about 3.3, but in my versions I set 0° the same as I would set 1°: by moving the slider down or clicking in the field and entering 0. Maybe the minimum value was changed in later versions.

Thank you so much! I'll definitely use the later version. For the "Roughness" value, I used a white plane to show the amount of light hitting the surface. So, I set the albedo to 1 (no absorption) and the roughness to 0. The reflection using the Oren-Nayar model (roughness = 1.0) changes based on the view angle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oren%E2%80%93Nayar_reflectance_model). However, the standard Lambertian model (cosine law) doesn't change with the view angle or the camera's position. (If I understand these  two models correctly.)
